# Joining rows while maintaining all columns

Tags: r, dataframe, join, merge, row

folx. Long time listener, first-time caller.
I have a df that looks like:

| ID | thing_1 | thing_2 | thing_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A001 | NA | YES | NA |
| A001 | YES | NA | NA |
| A002 | NA | NA | YES |
| A002 | NA | YES | NA |
| A002 | YES | NA | YES |
| A003 | NA | YES | NA |
| -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- |

I want it to look like:

| ID | thing_1 | thing_2 | thing_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A001 | YES | YES | NA |
| A002 | YES | YES | YES |
| A003 | NA | YES | NA |
| -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- |

All of the resources I found about joining rows concatenate all the columns' data into one column separated by commas or else they dealt with adding numerical values into a sum. I am dealing with characters. How do I maintain separate columns but squash all of the data into one row per ID?

Thanks!

Comment: IDK Why the second table looks so funky.

Comment: I got an answer elsewhere and thought I would share the result:  Dataset %>%
group_by(ID) %>%
summarize(THING1 = MAX(THING1),
                      THING2 = MAX(THING2),
                      THING3 = MAX(THING3)) %>%
ungroup()

Answer (score 1):

This is one approach with `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  fill(-ID, .direction="updown") %>% 
  distinct() %>% 
  ungroup()
# A tibble: 3 × 4
  ID    thing_1 thing_2 thing_3
  <chr> <chr>   <chr>   <chr>
1 A001  YES     YES     NA
2 A002  YES     YES     YES
3 A003  NA      YES     NA
```

##### Data

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c("A001", "A001", "A002", "A002", "A002",
"A003"), thing_1 = c(NA, "YES", NA, NA, "YES", NA), thing_2 = c("YES",
NA, NA, "YES", NA, "YES"), thing_3 = c(NA, NA, "YES", NA, "YES",
NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```